# How can I get a histogram/summary stats if I have a table with counts?

Tags: r, dataframe, histogram

I'm used to having a vector of observations like `c(1,1,1,3,4)` on which I can see summary statistics and plot histograms etc...but now I find myself with, the same data, but in a compressed format like this:

```
value, numObs
1, 3
3, 1
4, 1
```

How can I easily "unwrap" this easily into the vector or view the same summary stats or histogram plots when the data is expressed in a `data.frame` as above?

Comment: what output are you expecting? objects from class data.frame have a method for summary ... have you try at least summary(your_data_frame_name)?

Comment: I closed the other one since in my judgement they were dups and this had a better answer. Does make one wonder about homework, though, to see two very similar questions in quick succession. I suspect many other duplicates exist. Hence my downvote for failure to search.

Answer (score 2):

Unwrapping the data:

```
unwrapped <- rep(value, numObs)
```

If you're happy with the binning of your "compressed form" then see `?barplot` for plotting it. You would want to fill the zeros first, like:

```
v <- numeric(max(value))
v[value] <- numObs
barplot(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
with(df, rep(value, numObs))
```

where `df` is the name of your data.frame.